# When i set the margin in % what is the 100%?

Tags: css

So when i set a margin for example in an element like :
    margin:1% auto;

I assumed the 100% is the total width/top of the container,but thats not the case as i noticed, what does it take into account when it calculates that 1%?

Comment: RTFSpec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

Answer (score 0):

If your element is inside an other one, then the percentage is going to be based on the size of the parent.